# request callback, can't acces error, response and body

Tags: node.js, node-request

I'm creating an https request, to get some hidden variables on a sign in page. I'm using the node.js package request for this. After calling the request, I'm using a callback to go back to my parse function.

```
class h {
    constructor(username, password){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.secret12 = '';
    }

    init() {
        //Loading H without cookie
        request({
                uri: "http://example.com",
                method: "GET",
                jar: jar,
                followRedirect: true,
                maxRedirects: 10,
                timeout: 10000,
                //Need to fake useragent, otherwise server will close connection without response.
                headers: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}
            },
            this.getHiddenInputs());
    }

    getHiddenInputs(error, response, body) {

            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                //Parsing body of request, to get hidden inputs required to mock legit authentication.
                const dom = new JSDOM(body);
                this.secret12 = (dom.window.document.querySelector('input[value][type="hidden"][name="secret12"]').value);
            }
            else {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(response.statusCode)
            }
        };
}
const helper = new h("Username", "Password");

helper.init();
console.log(helper);
```

So after calling request inside init(). I'm using the callback function to run the code that finds the Hidden Input after it has completed the request. [I'm following the example from here.](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing `this.getHiddenInputs()` instead of passing it to request as a callback, so there is no actual callback given to the request call.

You could pass it like this `this.getHiddenInputs.bind(this)` or I'd prefer something like this `(error, response, body) => this.getHiddenInputs(error, response, body)`

Comment: So how would I call this.getHiddenInputs(), as the callback?

Comment: @JohnCadac Added 2 examples

Comment: I went for the lambda function, thanks for the examples!